# What are the differences between the alpine skiing events?

Tags: rules, olympics, skiing

The Olympics has five different alpine (downhill) skiing events:

- Downhill
- Slalom
- Giant Slalom
- Super Giant Slalom (Super-G)
- Super Combined

What are the differences between these different events?  I know that the number and spacing of the gates are different. Is that all it is, or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There some more differences:

- Slalom and giant slalow are technical events, super-G and downhill are speed events. Super combined, as the name implies, combines runs of slalom and downhill.
- Downhill and super-G events have one run, slalom and giant slalom events have two runs - different courses on the same ski run.
- Even the skis are different. Slalom skis are shorter and narrower, the better to manoeuvre quickly through gates which are close together without catching a tip on a gate. Giant slalom skis are longer and wider, but still not as long and wide as downhill skis.
- Slalom skiers need more protection - helmets, face guards, hand guards, and shin pads are compulsory. The extra equipment lets slalom skiers physically knock the poles out of the way as they pass, a special technique known as blocking.

Comment: It should also be noted that slalom and giant slalom events combine the times of the 2 runs (unlike other events where they only take your best run and throw away your worst runs).

Answer (score 4):

The main differences are about number of gates, distance from each gate, vertical drop and length of the course.

- Downhill
  Has the maximun of the lenght and the maximun distance from each gate. It runs on a single manche. It has the maximun speed.
- Super Giant Slalom (Super-G)
  It runs on a single manche.
- Giant Slalom
  The vertical drop for a GS course must be 250–450 metres (men), 250–400 m (women). The number of gates is 56–70 (men) and 46–58 (women). It runs on two manches, times of both runs is added up.
- Slalom
  Has the minimum of the length and the minimum distance from each gate. The course has 55-75 gates (men) and 40-60 (women). The vertical drop is 180-220 m (men) and slightly less for women. It runs on two manches, times of both runs are added up. It has the minimum value of speed.
- Super Combined
  It is a "small" downhill + a manche of slalom